# Alternative to Layoutit.com for Bootstrap that I can embed in my own app's backoffice

Tags: web-development, user-interface

[Layoutit.com](http://www.layoutit.com/) is a great tool for building simple HTML with the Bootstrap grid system.

I wish I can embed a tool (free or paid) like this in my own app's back office to allow users to build simples layout for the content.

After several searches, I'm unable to find any tool like that. Any tips? I could make one, but I do not want to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: A very good question. I am slowly migrating from Bootstrap Grid to [CSS grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_grid_layout) and might well ask a similar question for that

Comment: Wah! It already generates CSS grid too; now to see if we can embed something like it in our own apps

Answer (score 2):

This fits the requirements: 
https://github.com/savokiss/layoutit

[image]

Open source license (MIT, seems to contain some GPLv3 though).

Live demo: http://savokiss.me/layoutit/en/

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! This post does not contain enough information to be considered an answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it might be removed. Especially missing: how does it meet the requirements, what makes it recommendable, what about pricing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but if you want an alternative to Layoutit you can overhaul these.

1. [Jetstrap - tool paid](https://jetstrap.com/)
2. [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new#)
3. Rapidmoon

Comment: I want a tool similar to Layoutit.com or the ones you marked in your post, that I can download (not the result, but the tool itself) to embed in my backoffice.
The goal is to offer a similar tool to the users of my webapp, in my backoffice. They are not good in HTML so they will be able to design their own pages in my webapp.
Currently, these tools allows you to design a simple layout with drag&drop, and download the html markup result.
I want to offer similar tool into my backoffice, without needing to go to layoutit.com. dunno if I'm clear :)

Comment: @LaurentLevasseur The word you're looking for is "self-hosted" or "on-premises"

Comment: Yup. OP, pelase update your question for clarity (and use those terms in any Google search - especially self-hosted" )